# Angular Material: Update Text Content in Toast

Tags: angularjs, updates, angular-material, toast

I am attempting to use $mdToast.updateTextContent() to update a toast and am unsuccessful. The docs don't go into detail on how to call it with a new message. My desire result would have the first toast display 'Adding account' then change to 'account successfully added'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to approach this using material design standards would be to only use the toast once the account has been added. The loading could be a spinner or maybe a loading bar (maybe like this http://materializecss.com/preloader.html)

Answer (score 1):

Once the `$mdToast` is open, you're able to call `updateTextContent` (as you stated)

```
$scope.onAccountAdded = function() {
  $mdToast.updateTextContent('Account successfully added')
};
```

We're watching the variable for changes and update the view automatically, once the value has changed.

- https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/toast/toast.js#L299

Here is a demo, which shows how it works.

- http://codepen.io/DevVersion/pen/qNWewJ